# Eclipse/Aptana does not ctrl+tab between open files

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Aptana to develop a PHP site. I'm a .NET developer with some experience with PHP. I'm used to the highly robust Visual Studio and getting used to Aptana (built on the Eclipse core). When I have several files open I cannot ctrl+tab between them. Does anyone know how to turn that on? It's kind of pathetic if that's off by default.

Comment: Have you tried CTRL + E ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't worked with Aptana in a long time, but I've used Eclipse quite a bit, and I believe the tab-switching is bound to Ctrl+PgUp (or PgDown) by default.  I just recently installed Galileo, and used this as an opportunity to try rebinding to Ctrl+Tab, but didn't have any luck.

I know I got this to work on previous versions of Eclipse (at least Europa, and possibly Ganymede), but am not certain why it's not working in Galileo.  Regardless, here's how to find the key-bindings in an Eclipse install (I would assume Aptana uses these bindings as well):

Windows->Preferences->General->Keys

From there you can try filtering the key-binding you're looking for (e.g. "tabs" or something) and input whatever combo you want.

I would also recommend searching for the key-combo you're going to use to make sure it's not already in use.  If it is, you'll want to re-bind the conflicting binding, so they don't collide.

Answer (score 5):

Go to windows->Preferences->General->Keys. Type Next Tab and select the command "Next Tab" (Category All Aptana Editors). Unbind this command, edit the "Next Editor" command to ctrl+tab and voila!

Comment: This is alright... but it orders them in most recently used, rather than the order of the tabs on the screen, making it very different from similar apps

Comment: +1 I had the same issue with eclipse on ubuntu. Thanks for the solution. It works very well now :D

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac Book Pro running Leopard it's:

CTRL+FN+SHIFT UpArrow|DownArrow

Answer (score 1):

Actually all you need to do is CTRL + PageUp | PageDown

Answer (score 0):

fn+control+up/down on my macbook works

Comment: same for me in laptop or ctrl-pageup when using external keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old. As of today, I've still found a similar issue on Eclipse Juno after installing Aptana Plugin.

`Ctrl+Tab` used to work in Eclipse (since several versions, by now) before I installed Aptana. After installing Aptana, when hitting Ctrl+Tab I could see a small window flashing in the lower right corner of Eclipse window. That's the small yellow window popping up when you have multiple commands matching the same hotkeys.

There was a conflict on Ctrl+Tab hotkey between `Next Editor` and `Next Editor (Aptana)` commands. They both where active when `In Windows`.
To solve this specific issue, I just changed the `Next Editor (Aptana)` hotkey to be active when `In Aptana Editor`. HTH